# Queries responsible for high Created_tmp_disk_tables and Created_tmp_files

Tags: mysql

How to find out which queries are responsible for high `Created_tmp_disk_tables` and `Created_tmp_files` values? I know about `log_slow_filter` but I wonder if there is a way to figure it out for plain MySQL installation.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is not possible with native MySQL. You would have to use something like the [Percona Server](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.1/diagnostics/slow_extended.html?id=percona-server%3afeatures%3aslow_extended_51). Its easy enough to install so if you have a test box drop it on there, run your software for a few days, then check their log.

[How to use it](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/09/22/finding-what-created_tmp_disk_tables-with-log_slow_filter/).